# What is the file path for mydomain.com/shop/checkout/cart/couponPost?

Tags: magento-1.9

The application is posting a coupon from the site to this path and getting a 503. I do not know where this folder is in the application so I can troubleshoot. Can someone please advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pointing to a controller. The controller can be found in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php in your Magento root.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand the logic of the file paths. Is there a resource you can point me to so I can learn how the structure works? Thank you again.

Comment: This is a good tutorial, but only covers admin controllers. Should help though. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/tutorial-create-admin-manageable-magento-entity-brands/

Comment: Thank you. So, where can I find all the logic for a page on the frontend at http://example.com/shop/giftcard-balance/. It's broke and I need to hunt down why and I think it's an API password that changed.